# Unity, collider для импортированной модели

Tags: unity3d

Импортируются модель из 3dmax. Импорт проходит успешно. В свойстве prefaba задаю generate collider. Он генерируется как mesh collider. Однако при добавлении на объект Rigitbody модель проваливается сквозь пол. Как правильно настроить collider для модели?

Comment: А что за модель? А вообще вручную коллайдер добавь и все)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ сложная деталь не стандартной формы

Comment: Non-convex MeshCollider with non-kinematic Rigidbody is no longer supported in Unity 5.
If you want to use a non-convex mesh either make the Rigidbody kinematic or remove the Rigidbody component.

это так для справки) Кароче, не будет он с meshcollider(non convex) физику обрабатывать)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, проблем может быть несколько. Например, у объекта пола нет коллайдера. Либо пол и ваш объект имеют разные слои, а в настройках слоёв указано, что их столкновения не должны обрабатываться. Либо, один из коллайдеров может быть помечен, как IsTrigger и тогда он не будет сталкиваться, а только выдавать событие о пересечении.
Вообще этой банальной галочки должно быть достаточно для создания рабочего коллайдера. Т.е. если зелёный контур коллайдера совпадает с моделью, то проблема где-то в настройках окружающих объектов.